# $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is principal. And what are the units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

I have elements of the form $a+bi$. I have attempted to consider arbitrary ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. If $N$ is ideal and $N=\{0\}$ then it is generated by $0$.

If $N$ is not trivial, then exists $f=a+bi$ in $N$. But from here I do not see which direction I need to proceed to show that ideal needs to be principal...  Also I don't  see any units except $1$. I believe I am missing something very important. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Units are $\pm 1$. $\pm i$.  For PID, one way is to show the domain is Euclidean.

Comment: Indeed, likely the best way to proceed is the way @AndréNicolas suggests. In particular, considering the norm $N\colon \mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $N(a+bi) = (a+bi)(a-bi) = a^{2}+b^{2}$ might help you. The norm is also helpful in characterizing the units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Thanks! I think I finally have figured it out